# Creating recommended structure in SVN repository

Tags: svn, ubuntu

Well, i'm creating a svn repository with the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /home/svn
sudo svnadmin create /home/svn/odontonew
sudo chown -R root:root odontonew/
```

Finally, I need to create the recommended structred: trunk, tags and branches inside my "odontonew" folder.

So, my big question is: I should just make a `mkdir trunk tags branches` inside `odontonew` folder or i should use some svn command ? If have some special svn command, what is it ?

Well, i tried use : `sudo svn mkdir trunk` but i got the error: `svn: E155007: '/home/svn/odontonew' is not a working copy`

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of `svn mkdir` command:

- the one working on a path: in this case it assumes that this path is inside of a working copy and the change will be committed later, so no message is needed when creating a directory
- the one working with URL: in this case the directory is created remotely and commit message is needed

If you want to create a directory remotely you should pass something looking like an URL (e.g. file://...)

Comment: So, i found a better way to do it: I created the root repository and connected with my IDE ECLIPSE, and from eclipse i created the others needed folders like: trunk, branches and tags.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use svn commands to operate on the repository

Create a directory for your project in the repository:

```
svn mkdir --parents <REPO-URL>/<PROJ>/ -m "create project <PROJ>"
```

To create the trunk you could do an 'initial import' of your - not yet versioned - project

```
svn import <PROJ> <REPO-URL>/<PROJ>/trunk  -m "initial import project <PROJ>"
```

Now you can create the `branches` and `tags` directories:

```
svn mkdir --parents <REPO-URL>/<PROJ>/branches -m "initial import project <PROJ>"
svn mkdir --parents <REPO-URL>/<PROJ>/tags -m "initial import project <PROJ>"
```

To get your local project versioned, just do a `svn checkout` from the trunk

```
svn checkout --revision HEAD --depth infinity \ 
   --force <REPO-URL>/<PROJ>/trunk <PROJ>
```

Later if you want to create a branch after reaching some development state, you could just use the `svn copy` commad to copy from `trunk` to the `branches` directory

```
svn copy <REPO-URL>/<PROJ>/trunk <REPO-URL>/<PROJ>/branches/<_v_1.0_stable> \
   -m "create branche <PROJ_v_1.0_stable>"
```

Comment: When i executed the command: "sudo svn mkdir --parents odontonew -m="create project odontonew" " , i got the error: svn: E205009: Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or revision properties

Comment: @user2776409 svn complains that the `mkdir` command does not need a message, this is the  part specified with the option `-m`, which is actually strange because the [svn mkdir docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.mkdir.html) state that it is permited and it works for me (I have to say I have 1.7 svn client). Try to replace `=` with a space i.e. `-m " my message"`. If it doesnt work then try without. also you have to specify the url of the repository, you repository is `/home/svn/odontonew` which you have create using `svnadmin create ...`

Comment: @user2776409, If `odontonew` is your projects name then it is not very suitable for a repository name, of course you can have one repository dedicated to you project, but I wouldn't recommend that. Since you are working on the same machine on which the server is installed you yould use the file protokoll for the repository url: `sudo svn mkdir --parents file:///home/svn/odontonew/my_project -m "create project odontonew`.

Comment: @user2776409 Also I would recommend to use svn client `1.7`, it works also 1.6 svn server and has the benifit, that it creates one `.svn` forlder per working copy and not like `1.6` wich creates one in every sub directory in the working copy.